# Lighttpd file upload freezes server

Tags: ajax, upload, lighttpd

I am using a simple uploader through ajax, but until the file is uploaded the server will be unable to serve any other ajax calls.

Lighttpd version is : 1.4.36 .

This is a lighttpd problem : 
https://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/2130

Already tried:

```
server.max-worker = 2
```

But it doesn't work as intended.

What i would want is a workaround if anyone found one, so that i am able to make the server accepting and returning the other calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI: this is fixed in lighttpd git master and the fix will be part of the upcoming lighttpd 1.4.40 release.